# Input form with .change on drop down selector with dynamically created selections not working properly

Tags: jquery, ajax, onchange

I am building a form and I have it to where users can add or remove up to three vehicles from the form. In which they can pick a year make and model for each car. However when you choose three vehicles and then change it to two vehicles, if you have the second vehicle already defined before changing from three to two it resets the second vehicle. When in theory it should not. It should just remove the third vehicle.

I know there has to be something I'm missing or doing wrong. I am pretty sure it has something to do with the way the extra vehicles are created/removed. But I am not so sure.

```
    var total = $(this).val(); 
    //remove all
    $('.vehicleData').each(function(index)
    {
        if (index !== 0) $(this).remove();
    });
    //create new ones
    for (var i = 2; i <= total; i++)
    {   
        var vehicleTmp = 
            "<tr class='vehicleData'>" +
                "<td colspan='5'>" +
                    "<div class='vehicle'>" +
                        "<label>Vehicle " + i +": </label>" +
                        "Year: " + 
                        "<select name='year" + i + "' class='year' id='year" + i + "' size='1'>" +
                            "<option selected='selected' value=''>-- All Years --</option>" +                       
                        "</select> " + 
                        "Make: " +
                        "<select name='make" + i + "' class='make' id='make" + i + "' size='1'>" +
                            "<option value=''>-- All Makes --</option>" + 
                        "</select> " +
                        "Model: " +
                        "<select name='model" + i + "' class='model' id='model" + i + "' size='1'>" +
                            "<option value=''>-- All Models --</option>" + 
                        "</select> " + 
                    "</div>" +
                "</td> " +  
            "</tr>";

        $('.vehicleTable').append(vehicleTmp);
```

Its a little hard to tell in the JS Fiddle because of the lack of the connection to my php files its calling. But if you use firebug to watch the posts in the console it recalls them every time you change between two and three. I hope all that was clear enough.

http://jsfiddle.net/empire_eldest/gVgLP/5/

Is there something I am missing or doing wrong that will make it to where the vehicles that are already there won't be reset when changing the amount? Any input will be appreciated. Thanks!

*Note I know the code is kinda messy. I haven't had a chance to clean it up very well

Answer (score 0):

This is Happening because of the below line

```
$('.vehicleData').each(function (index) {
            if (index !== 0) $(this).remove();
        });
```

on change event,above line removes 2nd and 3rd vehicle (if they are present)
Now for use case when user changes no of vehicles from 3 to 2 then above line will remove second vehicle as well which you do not want.

to make it work ,you should change your if condition as

```
 if (index > (total-1)) $(this).remove();
```

and  also change the for loop condition as

```
for (var i = ($('.vehicleData').length+1); i <= total; i++)
```

Comment: I tried your suggested idea. Which I hadn't even thought of and it not only didn't fix the changing of both vehicles but with it, when you go from 2 or 3 down to 1 it gets rid of all vehicles and completely breaks it after that.

Comment: @Philip as per my last edit,i removed "=" in the if condition...is it still not working ?

Comment: Yeah I saw that as well. It fixed the removal of the first vehicle. But now when going back and forth from 2 to 3 you end up with 5 vehicles. And it still resets the second one. Do you think that it could be cause by the fact that on every change its checking for the extra vehicles and calling the ajax request for each vehicle?

Comment: @Philip I just corrected for loop condition as well...can you try now?

Comment: Sadly I was mistaken. I guess it just lagged a bit. But it stays when going from 3 to 2 but still resets from 2 to 3 :(

Answer (score 0):

in your code you have delete all records except the first one(0 index) -- using this line of code

```
$('.vehicleData').each(function(index)
{
    if (index !== 0) $(this).remove();
});
```

so if you want to delete the last record you need to delete the last table row(tr) from the record table as per your html structure. 
Or you can store the data in an array before your delete code and set the same.

Check this code hope it will fit perfect

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#id_NOV').change(function () {
        var total = $(this).val();

        var trs = $('table.vehicleTable tr').length;
        //create new ones

        if(trs > total) {
            do {
                $('table.vehicleTable tr:last').remove();
                trs--;
            } while(trs > total)
        }
        if(trs < total) {
            do{
                var vehicleTmp =
                    "<tr class='vehicleData'>" +
                    "<td colspan='5'>" +
                    "<div class='vehicle'>" +
                    "<label>Vehicle " + (trs + 1) + ": </label>" +
                    "Year: " +
                    "<select name='year" + (trs + 1) + "' class='year' id='year" + (trs + 1) + "' size='1'>" +
                    "<option selected='selected' value=''>-- All Years --</option>" +
                    "</select> " +
                    "Make: " +
                    "<select name='make" + (trs + 1) + "' class='make' id='make" + (trs + 1) + "' size='1'>" +
                    "<option value=''>-- All Makes --</option>" +
                    "</select> " +
                    "Model: " +
                    "<select name='model" + (trs + 1) + "' class='model' id='model" + (trs + 1) + "' size='1'>" +
                    "<option value=''>-- All Models --</option>" +
                    "</select> " +
                    "</div>" +
                    "</td> " +
                    "</tr>";

                $('.vehicleTable').append(vehicleTmp);
                trs++;
            }while(trs < total)
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: In the effort of learning. I tried your way @Sibashis it works when going from 2 to 3 but going the other way it still resets number 2 year. Only with a slight delay before it does so.

Comment: @Philip sorry for the late response, are u fix the issue yet, if not can you just update your jsfiddle example with latest code... I will focus on it what is the problem currently you faced as I could not understand from your reply.

Comment: I updated my fiddle. It can be hard to tell what really is going on. Due to the lack of connection to the database for the vehicles. However when you change the vehicle amount to 3, then fill out all three vehicles it works fine. Then if you change from 3 to 2 vehicles it works still. But when you go up from 2 vehicles to 3 it proceeds to reset the "year" field for the second vehicle but leaves the make and model as they were.